# zend framework 3 - get sql string

Tags: zend-framework3

I need to get the real sql string for a complex zend db sql abstraction. 
ZF2 had a function for this: 
$sql->getSqlstringForSqlObject($select);

is there an equivalent in ZF3 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can use `echo $sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($select)` to see the sql query. but recommnded way to do this now in ZF3 is `echo  $sql->buildSqlString($select);`

Answer (score 1):

I think it's same as in ZF2

```
//Zend\Db\Sql\Select
$select = $this->getSql()->select();

echo @$select->getSqlString();
```